# Are elements cached or not?

Tags: html, performance, caching

When I check with Privoxy what my browser downloads from one site, it seems like all the elements that make up the page (CSS, JS, icons, etc.) are redownloaded every time, ie. the browser doesn't cache them (Sorry, new uses aren't allowed to include URLs):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <TITLE>My Site</TITLE>
    <meta name="keywords" lang="fr" content="whatever">
    <meta name="Description" lang="fr" content="whatever">

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta name="Category" content="Internet"> 
    <meta name="revisit-after" content="2 days">
    <meta name="author" content="webmaster@example.com">
    <meta name="identifier-URL" content="http://www.example.com">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    <meta name="classification" content="Internet">
    <meta name="distribution" content="global">

    <meta name="geography" content="Paris">
    <meta name='language' content='fr'><meta http-equiv='content-language' content='fr'><meta name='rating' content='General'>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="My RSS" href="http://www.example.com/rss.php" />


    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="icon" href="animated_favicon1.gif" type="image/gif">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="miseenforme.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen2009.css" type="text/css">
    <!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen2009-ie6.css" type="text/css">
    <![endif]-->

    <style type="text/css">@import url(jscalendar-1.0/calendar-blue.css);</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jscalendar-1.0/calendar.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jscalendar-1.0/lang/calendar-fr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jscalendar-1.0/calendar-setup.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autogrow.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fonctionsjs.js?maj=v1"></script>
</head>
```

Fact is, I don't see any cache-related instructions in this HTML header.

Can someone confirm that browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome) don't cache anything unless told to in the HTML header?

Do we need to configure browsers to force them to cache elements?

Thank you.

Comment: I would expect that browsers respect HTTP headers, but in your case the cache behavior is not specified so you should check what the default behavior is for those browsers (or maybe for the http protocol).

Comment: "elements" in the title is misleading, it means something else - suggest you change to "resources" perhaps?

Comment: Others looking to help may want to see the additional info he posted in a reply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921630/are-elements-cached-or-not/922855#922855

Answer (score 1):

Short version: Don't change the browser, send the right cache related HTTP header* info.

Long version: If you don't explicitly tell the browser what and how to cache you leave it free to choose for itself. Such settings are configurable and vary enormously from user to user and browser to browser but typically you can expect the browser to aggressively cache images, js, and css, but not html (this is very rough and just my experience). It's not reasonable for you to rely on browsers to work it out though, if you care at all you need to explicitly tell them and you also need to do this with response headers rather than metatags because metatags are simply not respected.

Shorter version of the long version: caching is *complicated*. I advise you google a tutorial for your chosen language platform.

---

* *not* the contents of the html head tag, the contents of the HTTP header

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure they are not cached? If your server does not output a cache-control header for the static elements the browser will still issue an HTTP request (with the timestamp of the cached file) to the server for each element. The server should then respond with 304 status, not modified. So the file itself isn't transmitted again but this request-response might just be what you're seeing in Privoxy.

To save the requests you'd have to configure your server to set the cache-control header. However, note that changes on your server might then not reflect on the client, so you'll want to rename your css/static files whenever you change them to make sure all clients use the most up to date version.

Answer (score 0):

Caching (absent server configuration or other explicit instructions) is normally a browser setting for a lot of items. If you don't have a large enough cache set up, or you disabled caching, or your browser isn't sure its the same file, or any of a number of other possibilities, it will re-download the items.

There are some server controls you can set. If you let us know what server you're running you might get a better answer...

Lastly, you can look at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html and http://www.web-caching.com/mnot_tutorial/how.html for more information.

---

Based on [your reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921630/are-elements-cached-or-not/922855#922855) (I'm guessing that's you with a new name...) you want to look at your Apache settings. I've never used Apache so I wouldn't know where to start...

You're also going to want to look at some of the articles that I and others have linked to. This isn't exactly a simple topic. [One article](http://www.web-caching.com/mnot_tutorial/how.html) has been linked to a couple of times. (hint hint)

Not being a PHP programmer I'm not 100% certain on this, but I'm willing to bet that PHP has a way to override the server's cache header settings. Might be worth looking into here or at php.net.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the first thing to check is - Is caching disabled in your browser?

AFAIK, browsers do cache most page elements unless a browser setting or HTTP header in server response disables this caching.

The second thing would be to insert caching related headers in your output so that the browser is specifically instructed to cache all available information (for a set period).

[Here's an excellent tutorial](http://www.web-caching.com/mnot_tutorial/how.html) on the subject of Caching that helps to dispell many misconceptions about exactly how browser caching works.

Answer (score 0):

Use [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) to figure out what you should do to improve page loading performance. It also tells you what you should do to maximize the client side caching (i.e. in the browser).